# Automating powerpoint using python. How to access format axis objects

Tags: python, format, powerpoint, axis

Currently I'm working on Python to automate a powerpoint file. I'm using win32com.client to access the various objects needed. However I haven't been able to find any documentation on chart objects. can someone point me in the right direction.

```
import win32com.client

PPTApplication = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
PPTApplication.Visible = True
PPTFile = PPTApplication.Presentations.Open("D:\test.pptx")

x=PPTFile.Slides(1).Shapes("Chart1").Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1","C13").Value
```

The code above allows me to access the data for chart1.
How do I access the format axis options????
Or where can I find the documentation for the same.

Answer (score 0):

The PowerPoint Chart object API is documented here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff746468.aspx

The direction you'll want to head is `Chart.Axes()`, perhaps `Chart.Axes(xlValue)`.

Once you have the axis you want, you have the properties and methods listed here available to you:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff745187.aspx

In my experience, it sometimes takes some digging to come up with the path to the right attribute, but that's the general procedure.

Usually when I don't find what I'm looking for I search on 'vba powerpoint chart font color' or whatever specific call I'm looking for and the example VBA code shows the "path" through the object hierarchy to the property I need.

Comment: Hey Scanny, thanks a lot for helping out, the problem is that the VBA code is different from the win32com version. Eg. when I run the following command.    s1.Shapes("Chart 5").Chart.Axes.('xlValue').MaximumScale = 100    I get a response of Unknown Object. I was wondering if you know any location where I can get python code equivalents or anything similar?